# Whats the re module for replacing values with reggex?

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, python-2.7, python-re

Ok, so i m looking for 2 answers in one question. I need a regex and i need a regex module.
First for module which is the module that replaces somevalue(captured by regex) with other value.
Like if my input is

```
a=b
a=b&c=d
a=b&c=d&e=f
```

I should replace b,d,f with some value.
Secondly whats the regex for the given input

```
a=b
a=b&c=d
a=b&c=d&e=f
```

This is input and i couldnt think of any regex that mathes b,d,f and othre value if ? I need a regex for replacing b,d,f with a single value. Lets say that single value if 'HI'

EDIT: The input is actually a URL parameters ,i used urlparse then urlparsed_data.query
EDIT: Input can contain `[]` too. Like `a[]=b`

Comment: The input is actually a URL ,

Comment: Does [**this**](https://regex101.com/r/II6GLn/1) help?

Comment: yes it extracts correctly now i just need to replace =(\w) with =(myvalue), which function should i use

Comment: you can use `re.sub()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
line = 'a=b&c=d&e=f'  
re.findall(r'(\w+)=(\w+)', line)
```

Output

```
[('a', 'b'), ('c', 'd'), ('e', 'f')]
```

You will have enough information to continue.

```
line = 'a[]=b&c=d'
re.findall(r'([^&]+)=([^&]+)', line)
```

Output
[('a[]', 'b'), ('c', 'd')]

Comment: You method works too but it takes too much code to reform again https://imgur.com/a/9kFPpTH and https://imgur.com/a/T4PPxKD for now i m ticking you

Comment: Also you answer doesnt support `[]` tags, like if input is `r'a[]=b&c=d'` it fails to give output `('a[]', b)`. Update you answer more okay?, Also i will accept as answer if it accept `[]` too

Comment: It will match anything besides &. If you want to exclude anything will put it in between the [ and ].

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to replace the values `b`, `d` and `f` with a single value `HI`, would you please try:

```
import re
list1 = ['a=b', 'a=b&c=d', 'a[]=b&c=d&e=f', 'wrongurl']
for line in list1:
    if (re.match(r'([][\w]+=[^&=]+&)*[][\w]+=[^&=]+', line)):
        print(re.sub(r'=\w+', '=HI', line))
    else:
        print('Error: ' + line)
```

Output:

```
a=HI
a=HI&c=HI
a[]=HI&c=HI&e=HI
Error: wrongurl
```

Comment: Nice method goood